# Equivalent python 'in' on ruby

Tags: ruby

Im new to ruby, and i want to try translate a code python to ruby.What would be a simple, and similarly on this.

`print 'it has' if 'ten' in 'tentacle' else 'None'`

Answer (score 10):

Ruby `String` has method `include?` so it would be like:

```
print 'tentacle'.include?('ten') ? 'it has' : 'None'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rails, you can use 'in?':

```
puts 'ten'.in?('tentacle') ? 'it has' : 'None'
```